# MPandroidchart - Represent 4 points for each xValue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have my line chart with xVals = "`Su, Mo, Tu, Se, Th, Fr , Sa`", and I want to represent  28 points.

4 points for each xValue. ( Mo will have 4points, Tu will have 4 points, ....)

**I want to do this with multiple points in each xVal.**
[image]

Now I have, and I understand why.

```
One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object.
```

For this message error, I'm putting my xVals with "`Su , Su, Su, Su, Mo, Mo, Mo, Mo, Tu, Tu, Tu, Tu, Th, Th, Th, Th, Fr, Fr, Fr, Fr , Sa, Sa, Sa, Sa`". But I need to aggregate my xVals per weekday.

How I can solve this problem ?

Filipe this is the result of your suggestion:
I just replace my values for something random.

```
float somefloatvalue = (float) ((Math.random() * xIndex) + 3);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is **easily possible.**

You need to create 4 `DataSet` objects each containing 7 values (one for each day).

Your x-values array should only contain 7 values (one for each day).

You can find an example of how to create multiple datasets here:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/MultiLineChartActivity.java

Simplified example:

```
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    // add 7 days
    xVals.add("su"); xVals.add("mo"); xVals.add("tu"); xVals.add("we");
    xVals.add("th"); xVals.add("fr"); xVals.add("sa");

    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();

    // create 4 datasets
    for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        // loop through 7 days (xIndex 0 == su)
        for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < 7; xIndex ++) {
            float somefloatvalue = 1f;
            values.add(new Entry(somefloatvalue, xIndex));
        }

        LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet ");
        dataSets.add(d);
    }

    LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Didn't result. I updated my post with the result of your approach. Do you any idea?

Comment: You wanted to have 4 points for each x-value? Isn't the screenshot you posted exactly that?

Comment: The representation is different. Thinking in integers... If Mo = 0, and Su=1... I want to represent 4 points for xVal = 0. I will get (0, point1); (0.25, point2); (0.5, point3) ; (1, point4).
In your example, I have the 4 points in xval =1.
Did you understand?

Comment: So you are doing something 4 times a day but at different times during that day?
If that is not the case, I dont see an issue with using 4 datasets and having the entries above each other.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda cant we do this? doing something multiple times in a single day? if yes how we can do that, I am getting the same exception.